Fourier decay implies what kind of regularity
We consider a function $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb C$ that is compactly supported and bounded. In addition, we know that
$$\lim_{\vert x\vert \to \infty} \vert x \vert^2 \vert \hat{f}(x)\vert =0,$$
where $\hat{f}$ is the Fourier transform.
What can we say about the regularity of $f$?
I am particularly interested if the fact that $\lim_{\vert x\vert \to \infty} \vert x \vert^2 \vert \hat{f}(x)\vert =0,$ implies anything better than if we would only assume
$$\sup_{x} \vert x \vert^2 \vert \hat{f}(x)\vert <\infty.$$

I suppose that $f$ is at least measurable (hence $L^1$ and identified with a tempered distribution in $\mathbb{R}^2$). The validity of the first limit follows (from the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma) if the (distributional) Laplacian $\Delta f$ of $f$ is in $L^1$ as well. However, since the Fourier transform maps $L^1$ into but not onto $C_0$, it may not be true that $\Delta f\in L^1$ with your hypothesis alone. Also, unfortunately you are "on the wrong side" of the Sobolev embedding theorem, so the latter result most likely won't help you either...

Another thing that follows from the fact that $f$ is (measurable, ) compactly supported and bounded is that $\hat{f}$ is a polynomially bounded real analytic function, by the Paley-Wiener-Schwartz theorem. Your final hypothesis just strengthens the polynomial bound on $\hat{f}$. However, that additional regularity on $\hat{f}$ doesn't seem to bring anything new to the considerations in my previous comment.
